# delay in playing rtsp stream

Tags: streaming, rtsp, vlcj

I'm experimenting with rtsp streams in java using vlcj in windows 7 system.i found a 5 seconds delay in displaying the video.i tried to write it to a temporary  .mpg file.how can i feed the contents of that file to the player while streaming progresses?